# Everything up-to-date, but i still get 1 commit ahead, 2 commits behind :/

Tags: git, gitk

I had a issue with 7 commits ahead of main, 1 behind..., somehow fixed, partially. But I still get 1 commit ahead, 2 commits behind. Doing

```
git rebase master
git push --force-with-lease origin myfeature
```

on both branches and `writes up-to-date`. Everything is committed in `feature` branch.
Anybody, would appreciate some help.

[image: gitk --all screenshot]

P.S. I know, i have to take a git course...

Comment: Could you start up `gitk --all` and have a look at what it tells? Possibly attach a screen shot.

Comment: @hlovdal sure. but i did few more tries with pull and push and now it writes 
` tango branch is 4 commits ahead of main. `
sec screenshot

Comment: @hlovdal
[screenshot of gitk --all](https://paste.pics/163d1b38a0666f7fb05cd4fbf14ca8a7)

Comment: You need to embed the screenshot directly in the answer. Stackoverflow has its own associated image hosting service. Using other, external services are guarantied to lead to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: @hlovdal okay, i hope this works. 
![screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzwPj.png)

Comment: The screen shot has two branches, `main` and `tango` while the question references `master` and `myfeature`. Was this the same repository?

Comment: @hlovdal Yes, the same repo. I just used some generic names.

Comment: The "ahead/behind" message appears when you run `git status`, doesn't it ? Can you copy/paste the entire message on your question ?

Answer (score 1):

One blind bet : your local `tango` branch doesn't track the branch you expect. Run `git branch --set-upstream origin/tango` from your `tango` branch.

Comment: Running git status i got - nothing to commit on both repos. Ahead/behind was appearing on github website on tango. Anyways, somehow got my main branch up to date with latest changes. Best would be to take a course so i know the correct workflow. Still, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: oh, then it's probably `tango` compared to `master`